# How can I configure package.json in order to run "istanbul cover" for all .js files?

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, istanbul

```
"scripts" : {
    "coverage" : "istanbul cover ./test.js"
}
```

Above code runs coverage operation for the specific js file when I enter:

```
npm run coverage
```

How can I change it so it can run for every .js file in the project (or a specific directory)?

Edit: Tried "istanbul cover -i ./**/*.js" as suggested, here is the screenshot of the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `"coverage" : "istanbul cover -i ./**/*.js"`

Comment: I get this error: npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "coverage"

Comment: I've added `-i` flag. Try using it now

Comment: Still having errors, edited my post with a screenshot.